# Модель сущность-связь

Tags: sql

Как сделать ERD (entity-relashionship diagram) в sql?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. SQL это язык запросов на получение/изменение данных, а  ER-диаграмма - это схема, иллюстрирующая, как эти данные организованы. Если же вам нужно сгенерировать диаграмму по существующей базе, то есть множество программ. Погуглите [ER reverse engineering](http://www.google.ru/webhp?hl=ru#hl=ru&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=22&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=ER+reverse+engineering&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&newwindow=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=ER+reverse+engineering&aq=0vL&aqi=g-vL2&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f57c15f5735f30b7&biw=1680&bih=935)